# Testing text of an animated label that appears and disappears

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest

I am struggling to test the appearance of a label(toastLabel) which I have that animates briefly into view when someone enters the wrong email.

```
private func registerNewUser(email: String, password: String, confirmationPassword: String) {
    if password == confirmationPassword {
        firebaseData.createUser(email: email, password: password, completion: { (error, _ ) in
            if let error = error {
                self.showToast(in: self.view, with: error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                self.showToast(in: self.view, with: "Registered succesfully")
                self.signInUser(email: email, password: password)
            }
        })
    } else {
        //raise password mismatch error
        print("password mismatch error")
    }
}

func showToast(in toastSuperView: UIView, with text: String) {
    let toastLabel = ToastLabel()
    toastLabel.text = text
    toastSuperView.addSubview(toastLabel)
    layoutToastLabel(toastLabel)
    animateToastLabel(toastLabel)
}

private func layoutToastLabel(_ toastLabel: ToastLabel) {
    toastLabel.centerYToSuperview()
    toastLabel.pinToSuperview(edges: [.left, .right])
}

private func animateToastLabel(_ toastLabel: ToastLabel) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        toastLabel.alpha = 0.0
    }, completion: { _ in
        toastLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}
```

I just want to test that the error text received back from firebase appears after the user enters an email that has already been taken.

```
func testRegisteringWithUsedEmailDisplaysFirebaseError() {
    let email = registeredEmail
    let password = "password"

    welcomeScreenHelper.register(email: email,
                                 password: password,
                                 confirmationPassword: password,
                                 completion: {

        let firebaseErrorMessage = "The email address is already in use by another account."
        XCTAssert(self.app.staticTexts[firebaseErrorMessage].exists)
    })
}

func register(email: String, password: String, confirmationPassword: String, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    let emailTextField = app.textFields[AccesID.emailTextField]
    let passwordTextField = app.secureTextFields[AccesID.passwordTextField]
    let confirmPasswordTextField = app.secureTextFields[AccesID.confirmPasswordTextField]
    let registerButton = app.buttons[AccesID.registerButton]

    emailTextField.tap()
    emailTextField.typeText(email)
    passwordTextField.tap()
    passwordTextField.typeText(password)
    registerButton.tap()
    confirmPasswordTextField.tap()
    confirmPasswordTextField.typeText(confirmationPassword)
    registerButton.tap()

    completion?()
}
```

when I use other tools such as expectation and XCTWaiter the tests still don't pass despite the text and label definitely appearing. I have never had to do a test like this so I'm not sure where I may be going wrong, whether I have to do something different to test an animated view or something.

Update1:

So I can see after a bit more playing that when i tap the registerButton the toast appears as it should but the test doesn't continue until it has disappeared again. I find this odd as it's not strictly attached to the registerButton being its own view.

update2:

I have update my test as follows:

```
func testRegisteringWithUsedEmailDisplaysFirebaseError() {

    welcomeScreenHelper.register(email: registeredEmail,
                                 password: password,
                                 confirmationPassword: password,
                                 completion: {

        let firebaseErrorMessage = "The email address is already in use by another account."

        let text = self.app.staticTexts[firebaseErrorMessage]
        let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")

        self.expectation(for: exists, evaluatedWith: text, handler: nil)
        self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 10, handler: nil)
        XCTAssert(self.app.staticTexts[firebaseErrorMessage].exists)
    })
}
```

with the addition of:

```
override func setUp() {
    app.launch()
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    super.setUp()
}

override func tearDown() {
    if let email = createdUserEmail {
        firebaseHelper.removeUser(with: email)
    }
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    super.tearDown()
}
```

But so far no luck. I can still see that in `func register` once the register button is tapped the toast shows and the next line isn't called until the toastLabel has finished animating.

Comment: It's hard though to spot the problem in your code — there are some methods but context is missing. Like: `func testRegisteringWithUsedEmailDisplaysFirebaseError()` is definitely in `class MyTest: XCTestCase`; is `func register(email: String, password: String, confirmationPassword: String, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)` also a method of `MyTest`? Seems like a stub method. Are you injecting `firebaseData` somehow? Giving more context would definitely improve the question quality.

Comment: Please, check the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things you need to solve in such kind of test:

1. If the code you are testing is using `DispatchQueue.async` you should use `XCTestCase.expectation`
2. If the code you are testing has `UIView.animate` in it (I see there is one in your example) do `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)` before the test and enable it back after the test finishes so expectation won't wait for animation to complete. You can do it in `XCTestCase.setUp` and `XCTestCase.tearDown` methods.
3. If the code you are testing has dependencies like services that are doing async calls (I assume `firebaseData` is) you should either inject their mocks/stubs that will behave synchronously or use `XCTestCase.expectation` and pray for API/network be OK while the tests are run.

So using `XCTestCase.expectation` + `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)` should work for you. Just `XCTestCase.expectation` with high enough timeout should work too.

EDIT 1:
Correct way to use expectation:

```
func test() {
    let exp = expectation(description: "completion called")
    someAsyncMethodWithCompletion() {
        exp.fulfill()
    }
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 1) { _ in }
    // assert here
}
```

So your test method should be:

```
func testRegisteringWithUsedEmailDisplaysFirebaseError() {
    let exp = expectation(description: "completion called")
    welcomeScreenHelper.register(email: registeredEmail,
                                 password: password,
                                 confirmationPassword: password,
                                 completion: { exp.fulfill() })
    self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 10, handler: nil)
    let firebaseErrorMessage = "The email address is already in use by another account."
    XCTAssert(self.app.staticTexts[firebaseErrorMessage].exists)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, the code doesnt use DispatchQueue at all at the moment, but it does use UIView.animate for the toast. I did as you have mentioned as you can see in my update2 in the question but get the same failed result. With regards to your other comment i am not mocking or stubbing anything the `register` method is just contained within a helper class and firebase isnt injected anywhere but it does get called if there are no errors in what the user has entered. The errors are presented in a toast which is what im trying to test for. Thanks